# GWT. Detect when TextBox'es text chaged.

Tags: java, gwt

I need to programmatically set text into `TextBox` and catch event when text was changed. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setValue("my new value", true);`? This will fire an `ValueChangeEvent`, which you can catch by adding a `ValueChangeHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following

```
yourTextBox.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
@Override
     public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but it dont work. Read my comment